# Paging Resultsets in Cassandra with compound primary keys - Missing out on rows

Tags: cassandra, cql3

So, my original problem was using the token() function to page through a large data set in Cassandra 1.2.9, as explained and answered here: [Paging large resultsets in Cassandra with CQL3 with varchar keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23610771/paging-large-resultsets-in-cassandra-with-cql3-with-varchar-keys)

The accepted answer got the select working with tokens and chunk size, but another problem manifested itself.

My table looks like this in cqlsh:

```
key           | column1               | value
---------------+-----------------------+-------
  85.166.4.140 |       county_finnmark |     4
  85.166.4.140 |       county_id_20020 |     4
  85.166.4.140 |     municipality_alta |     2
  85.166.4.140 | municipality_id_20441 |     2
 93.89.124.241 |        county_hedmark |    24
 93.89.124.241 |       county_id_20005 |    24
```

The primary key is a composite of key and column1. In CLI, the same data looks like this:

```
get ip['85.166.4.140'];
=> (counter=county_finnmark, value=4)
=> (counter=county_id_20020, value=4)
=> (counter=municipality_alta, value=2)
=> (counter=municipality_id_20441, value=2)
Returned 4 results.
```

**The problem**

When using cql with a limit of i.e. 100, the returned results may stop in the middle of a record, like this:

```
key           | column1               | value
---------------+-----------------------+-------
  85.166.4.140 |       county_finnmark |     4
  85.166.4.140 |       county_id_20020 |     4
```

leaving these to "rows" (columns) out:

```
  85.166.4.140 |     municipality_alta |     2
  85.166.4.140 | municipality_id_20441 |     2
```

Now, when I use the token() function for the next page like, these two rows are skipped:

```
select * from ip where token(key) > token('85.166.4.140') limit 10;
```

Result:

```
key           | column1                | value
---------------+------------------------+-------
 93.89.124.241 |         county_hedmark |    24
 93.89.124.241 |        county_id_20005 |    24
 95.169.53.204 |        county_id_20006 |     2
 95.169.53.204 |         county_oppland |     2
```

So, no trace of the last two results from the previous IP address.

**Question**

How can I use token() for paging without skipping over cql rows? Something like:

```
select * from ip where token(key) > token(key:column1) limit 10;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I used the info in this post to work out a solution:
http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-table-support-in-hadoop-pig-and-hive
(section "CQL3 pagination").

First, I execute this cql:

```
select * from ip limit 5000;
```

From the last row in the resultset, I get the key (i.e. '85.166.4.140') and the value from column1 (i.e. 'county_id_20020').

Then I create a prepared statement evaluating to

```
select * from ip where token(key) = token('85.166.4.140') and column1 > 'county_id_20020' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

(I'm guessing it would work also without using the token() function, as the check is now for *equal*:)

```
select * from ip where key = '85.166.4.140' and column1 > 'county_id_20020' ALLOW FILTERING;
```

The resultset now contains the remaining X rows (columns) for this IP. The method then returns all the rows, and the next call to the method includes the last used key ('85.166.4.140'). With this key, I can execute the following select:

```
select * from ip where token(key) > token('85.166.4.140') limit 5000;
```

which gives me the next 5000 rows from (and including) the first IP *after* '85.166.4.140'.

Now, no columns are lost in the paging.

**UPDATE**

Cassandra 2.0 introduced automatic paging, handled by the client. 
More info here: http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/client-side-improvements-in-cassandra-2-0

(note that setFetchSize is optional and not necessary for paging to work)